# Enable Office Add-in only on the Web version of office products

Tags: office365, office-js, manifest, office-addins

We use XML Manifest for Office Add-ins which were deployed using Centralized Deployment method in Azure active directory.
Ideally, we were trying to implement our document classification feature in Office(online) task pane by using these manifest Office Add-ins. 
On the other hand, We have a stable desktop office VSTO Add-in for classifying documents.

That being said, newly added Manifest Office Add-in is showing up in our desktop versions of Office, which we don't want to display since we already have a desktop version of software.
I looked for the documentation related to Office Add-in and manifests from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1 ,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins-fundamentals , 
and an existing compatability check from here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/make-office-add-in-compatible-with-existing-com-add-in
None of these options gives us any convening answer on not to display the Office-js Add-in on desktop version, 
since we also looking for not to display the office-js add-in irrespective of the existence of equivalent COM-Addin.

In a nutshell, my goal is to restrict the office add-in task pane to online version only and not to display in desktop version of office.Any helpful information or any equivalent workaround in JS is much appreciated to solve this basic problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to office JS world.

I am sorry, you may not specify which platform can be used to run your add-in, which is by design. As the advantage of web-addin is be able to cross platforms. 
So the Office store requires that the add-in works for Mac, Windows, and Online with optional iPad support. It is not possible to select only some of the required platform. as your code work on Excel Online should also work on Windows

But you still have chances to do a [runtime check the host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#use-runtime-checks-in-your-javascript-code) in your JavaScript code. You may be able to do something here. here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).